# Concatenate values in multiple rows in a table and write it to a cell in a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate the values in multiple rows from a column in a table and write it to a single cell in another table. Both the tables are on a mysql database.
E.g.

Input would be like:

```
tno t1  t2
1   a   c
1   b   d
2   e   g
2   f   h
3   i   k
3   j   l
```

Output would look like:

```
   tno  text
    1   abcd
    2   efgh
    3   ijkl
```

The order 'abcd' or 'acbd' wouldn't matter much.

Anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`, like this:

```
SELECT tno, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t1,t2) SEPARATOR '') AS `text`
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY tno
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c2d7/2

Comment: Don't forget the INSERT statement to put it in the other table!